# Unbalanced data set - how to optimize hyperparams via grid search?

Tags: scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, gridsearchcv, imbalanced-data, smote

I would like to optimize the hyperparameters C and Gamma of an SVC by using grid search for an unbalanced data set. So far I have used class_weights='balanced' and selected the best hyperparameters based on the average of the f1-scores. However, the data set is very unbalanced, i.e. if I chose GridSearchCV with cv=10, then some minority classes are not represented in the validation data. I'm thinking of using SMOTE, but I see the problem here that I would have to set k_neighbors=1 because in some minority classes there are often only 1-2 samples. Does anyone have a tip how to optimized the hyperparameters in this case? Are there any alternatives?

Many thanks for every hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to optimize the hyperparameters C and Gamma of an SVC by using grid search for an unbalanced data set. Does anyone have a tip how to optimized the hyperparameters in this case?

You could use the GridSearchCV() function doing something like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 


param_grid = {'C': [0.1, 5, 50, 100],  
              'gamma': [1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01]}  

model = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid, refit = True) 

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You could use [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) in order to explore more options.

> I'm thinking of using SMOTE, but I see the problem here that I would have to set k_neighbors=1

Did you try [ADASYN](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN.html)?

> Are there any alternatives?

When I am really lost, I try a "last resource". It is a tool called [tpot](https://epistasislab.github.io/tpot/).

Just doing an example like this one:

```
tpot = TPOTClassifier(generations=5, population_size=50, scoring='roc_auc', verbosity=2, random_state=42)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
tpot.export('tpot_results.py')
```

It will output an sklearn code, with an algorithm and a pipeline, in this case the tpot_results.py would be:

```
tpot_data = pd.read_csv('PATH/TO/DATA/FILE', sep='COLUMN_SEPARATOR', dtype=np.float64)
features = tpot_data.drop('target', axis=1)
training_features, testing_features, training_target, testing_target = \
            train_test_split(features, tpot_data['target'], random_state=42)

# Average CV score on the training set was: 0.9826086956521738
exported_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    Normalizer(norm="l2"),
    KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, p=2, weights="distance")
)
# Fix random state for all the steps in exported pipeline
set_param_recursive(exported_pipeline.steps, 'random_state', 42)

exported_pipeline.fit(training_features, training_target)
results = exported_pipeline.predict(testing_features)
```

Be careful with overfitting problems when using this tool, but is one alternative that I can recommend you.